# xml error for ajax request

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have data stored in xml format, inside the file test.txt,

```
<element-list>
    <element>
        <name>sam</name>
        <title>header</title>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>3732</id>
        <name>mad</name>
        <title>header</title>
    </element>
</element-list>
```

I am trying to access that file using ajax request  using the code,

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    //url : "http://localhost:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search?uid=1&query="+$("#srchBox").val() ,
    url: 'json/test.txt',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success : function result(s){           
        console.log(s.element[k].term[j] + "  /  " + s.element[k].title) ;              
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
        console.log(xhr.responseText + " / " + xhr.status);
        //showError('an unknown error occurred while trying to fetch the feed: ' + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

gives me  no response other than error?? what could be wrong??

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, are you sure you're not getting a 404, file not found? What kind of error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

`s` is an `XMLDocument` you can use jQuery to access its nodes

```
console.log($(s).find('element').eq(k).find('term')[j].text() + "  /  " + $(s).find('element')[k].find('title').text());
```

Also what you are looking for doesn't seem to match what you have in your xml file.